# Local extrema of $f(x):=\begin{cases}|x|,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0,&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}.\end{cases}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

> Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x):=\begin{cases}|x|,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0,&x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}.\end{cases}$
>
> Find all local extrema!

1.) $f$ attains at $a_1=0$ and all $y\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ local minima because $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

2.) Let's choose an arbitrary $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ and an arbitrary $\epsilon$ such that $0<\epsilon<|x|$, then we always find a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$ and $x-\frac{1}{n}<x<x+\frac{1}{n}\implies f(x-\frac{1}{n})<f(x)<f(x+\frac{1}{n})$. The same holds with flipped inequality signs if $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{<0}$. Hence, $f$ can't attain local extrema in any rational point, except $0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: What part do you have questions about, specifically? We aren't [supposed to be] a proof-checking site...

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct! The elements of $S = \{0\} \cup \mathbb{I}$ are **all** the local minima, denoting $\mathbb{I} = \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ the irrational numbers. Proving that the elements of $S$ are local minima is trivial, as $f(x) = 0 \leq f(y)$, for $x \in S$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, to prove that these elements are the **only** local minima, you can argue by contradiction following your argument, which I will write next for further clarification. Let's assume there exist a non-zero rational number, $z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$, that is a local minima. By definition, there must exist an interval $V = (z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon) \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(z) \leq f(v)$, for all $v \in V$. However, you can always find a natural number $N_0$ big enough so that $1/N_0 < \epsilon$ and $1/N_0 <|z|$. You can then state that the three numbers $z$, $z-1/N_0$, and $z+1/N_0$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$ and in $V$. There are two options:

a) If $z>0$, then $f(z-1/N_0) = |z-1/N_0| < f(z) |z| < f(z+1/N_0) = |z+1/N_0|$

a) If $z<0$, then $f(z-1/N_0) = |z-1/N_0| > f(z) |z| > f(z+1/N_0) = |z+1/N_0|$

In either case you have that $z$ is not a minima in the interval $V$, finding a contradiction. And please note I selected $1/N_0 <|z|$ as well so that the three analyzed rational numbers are, either all of them positive, or all of them negative.